# Open source FTP client which is Block mode enabled

Tags: java, python, ruby, perl, ftp-client

I have to send data to legacy FTP server which "MODE BLOCK" and "STRUCT RECORD" or "MODE B" and "STURCT R" are mandatory.

Is there any open source FTP client on linux or programming library which "MODE BLOCK" and "STRUCT RECORD" functions are enabled? (Preferably FTP Client on linux).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the JavaDOC for Apache Commons FTP library, it looks as though constants exist for this functionality.

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTP.html

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTP.html#BLOCK_TRANSFER_MODE

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTP.html#RECORD_STRUCTURE

Comment: Thank you for the information, we came up to the conclusion which is to change the server side logic. Thank you anyway.